# How to track changes to AWS WAF Web ACL using AWS Config?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-config, aws-waf, aws-waf-web-acl

As stated in [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-config-adds-support-for-aws-waf-and-amazon-cloudfront/#:%7E:text=With%20Config%2C%20you%20can%20now,Balancer%20associations%20and%20default%20actions.), we can track changes to AWS WAF Web ACL using AWS Config. I created a `WAF Web ACL` and associated it with an `API Gateway Rest API`. How to track changes (create/update/delete) to this Web ACL?

**What I tried?**

I tried to create an AWS managed rule in AWS Config. I could not find any rule which 'tracks changes to AWS WAF Web ACL'.

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: `AWS::WAF::WebACL` is a [supported resource type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html). What changes do you want to track? In general you can check the resource timeline for any recorded resource to see all changes.